# HTML Drop-down menu to retain selection on page refresh?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, selection

Is there anyway to do this is pure html without java?

The current html is as follows:

```
<form name="form1">
<select name="menu" onChange="location=document.form1.menu.options[document.form1.menu.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=''></option>
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>?product_order=DESC">A-Z</option>
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>?product_order=ASC">Z-A</option>
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Price</option>
<option value="<?php the_permalink() ?>?product_order=id">Recently Added</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This works, the page reloads and the sorting is applied BUT the selection in the dropdown box returns to blank - I'd like it to display the 'active' selection?

Answer (score 1):

add in `selected="selected"` anywhere within the option tag

whichever one this is added to will remain selected, simply change your php/perl/python (whatever language) to add this code to one which is selected by the user through your $_POST value

for example if you wanted the last option to be selected, this would be the html code

```
<option selected="selected" value="<?php the_permalink() ?>?product_order=id">Recently Added</option>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a very 'newbie' question but my php is lacking, how would I use the $_POST in the above code?

Comment: your user inputs the data, you will be retrieving the data with the $_POST value it inputs, correct? Use this input data to determine which value was selected, and output the new data with the selected tag on the correct option

Comment: So I use $_POST to insert selected="select" to one of the options?

Comment: no, you use php for that, you use post to get the users input... this is simple coding, i shouldnt need to explain this.

Comment: I don't know PHP and I'm attempting to learn, Googling the subject has confused me somewhat, sorry for trying your patience.